# Bat script cmd to console2

Tags: console2

In some .bat file I have the following line

```
start "tomcat product" cmd /K mvn tomcat7:run  %ENV_PARAMS% -P%MAVEN_PROFILE%
```

I want to change it to use console2 instead of cmd but without luck.

Anyone can help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

I know a little late, but in case someone still needs:

To start a program within console2 use
`Console.exe -r program.exe`

In case you need to run it in a specific tab of console2 use the `-t` parameter with your tab name.

```
-t <tab name>
 Specifies a startup tab. Tab must be defined in Console settings.

-r <command>
 Specifies a startup shell command.
```

Example.bat:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Console2\Console.exe" -r "/K notepad.exe" -t "cmd"
```

runs console2 which opens notepad.exe in the tab called `cmd`.